# I found the argument for why $\sup(a,b) = b$ in my textbook unconvincing. Please advice.

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Here's the proof for why $\sup(a,b) = b$ in AOPS Calculus:

$x < b$ for any $x ∈ (a, b)$, so $b$ is an upper bound.

$x ∈ (a, b)$ for any $x ∈ \Bbb R$ and $a < x < b$, so there is no upper bound less than $b$ $⟹ \sup(a, b) ≥ b \quad(1)$

But $\sup(a,b) ≤ b$ by definition. $\quad(2)$

From $(1), (2)$, we conclude that $\sup(a, b) = b$

I feel there is a logical leap in the line that leads to point (1). It's intuitive, but I wondered if it's possible to prove it more rigorously.

Suppose there is an upper bound $c$ less than $b$, then c must satisfy:
$$\begin{cases}c < b \\ c ≥ x \,\, for \,\, all \,\, x ∈ (a, b)\end{cases}$$

This implies that $c ∈ (a,b)$.

Such an upper bound $c$ doesn't exist because we could always find a number $x ∈ (a,b)$ that is greater than $c$. But how do we prove this statement?

Comment: what about $x=\frac{c+b}{2}$?

Comment: @JonasLenz omg I feel dumb. Thank you so much!

Comment: (1) and (2) are both unnecessary imo. All you need is that $b$ is an upper bound and there’s no upper bound less than $b$, in other words $b$ is the least upper bound, by definition $b=\sup(a,b)$

Comment: You are absolutely right that this proof from the book is non rigorous.

Comment: @Divide1918 Now that you said it, that makes sense! Thanks for pointing that out!